# Can anyone help me with this C program?

Tags: c, printf

I've just started to learn coding

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0, x=0;

    for (i=1; i<=100; i++) {

        x++;
        if (x%5==0 || x%3==0)
            printf("The numbers are : %d\n", &x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so I'm trying to print all the integers <=100 that are divisible by either 3 or 5.

Comment: Remove the ampersand.

Comment: After that, print the announcement before the loop, and just the number within the loop. Then simplify further by using a single variable `i`. Replace `x` with `i` and remove `x++`

Comment: Did you enable all compiler warnings? Did you read them? You should see a warning like `format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'`.

Comment: SORRY! I know there shouldn't be an ampersand there! It was a typing mistake. It's working now! :) :)

Comment: what if I put i=0 inside the for loop instead of i=1?

Comment: Rolled back. Don't edit your question leaving answers without context.

Comment: Although removing the `&` fixes a problem, the real issues is that your compiler did not warn you about this.  Save time.  Insure all warnings are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
printf("the numbers are : %d", &x);
```

`printf` is expecting an integer because of the `%d` format specifier, you have given it the address of an integer, thats what the `&` means, address of `x`. To fix this give `printf` what it desires, an `int`:

```
printf("the numbers are : %d", x);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand (`&`) operator returns the *address* of a variable, which isn't what you want - you just want the value. Also, note that you don't need two variables (`x` and `i`) - you can just use the loop's counter:

```
printf("The numbers are:\n");
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0 || i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit that and change the second x to i, too.

Comment: `printf("%d", i);` The output from this in a loop will be pretty unreadable. You either need a newline or some space between numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the & will eliminate the error. You may also want to move the "the numbers are:" statement outisde of the loop so the text does not print each time through the loop.

Comment: Just curious - how does your answer improve the other, identical, answers?